# building older package from git

Tags: scripts, vps

Im trying to run a older version of xdotool and this is what i do:

```
git init
pwd
git checkout edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8
```

but it return me with this error:

```
fatal: reference is not a tree: edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8
```

How do i build an older version of a program correctly using git?

Edit:
So after searching online i found that i need to add a "." at the end so this would be it:

```
 git checkout edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8.
```

but now it gives me this error:

```
 error: pathspec '.edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: Did you miss a space before the period? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo

Comment: @nickhansenrf i also tryed with space but then it gives me the error: fatal: reference is not a tree

Comment: Did you forget to download the repo?

Comment: You don't need a dot

Comment: @wjandrea where do i download the repo?

Comment: @RapidGainz Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I will put some compile instructions together for your version...

Comment: @andrew.46 sorry for the late reply, im using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 2):

The git application is *not* required to download a specific revision of xdotool. For GitHub you can download an archive with a specific shasum using the following URL format:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{sha}.tar.gz
```

So for your needs the following should suffice:

```
wget https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/archive/edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8.tar.gz
```

And that should be enough to get you going :)

**References:**

- [How to download .zip from GitHub for a particular commit sha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636559/how-to-download-zip-from-github-for-a-particular-commit-sha) A stack overflow site question and answer that pretty much covers this question...

Comment: when its done downloading the .tar.gz it says it saves it here: Saving to: 'edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8.tar.gz' but i cannot run the package

Comment: BTW for anyone who's not familiar with `tar` (including myself), the command to extract it is `tar -xf edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8.tar.gz`. The output is a dir called `xdotool-edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8`.

Comment: @wjandrea it gives me the same errors as when using git :(

Comment: @RapidGainz This is not a package but the source code alone, from here you need to create the package or simply compile and install. Not quite what you were after?

Comment: @andrew.46 i did try to compile and install it but it returns me with errors: 'Makefile:121: recipe for target 'xdo.o' failed' and 'make: *** [xdo.o] Error 1' and 'xdo.c:24:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory #include <X11/Xlib.h>'

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the repo on your machine. You need to download it first, for example using `git clone`:

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool.git
~$ cd xdotool
~/xdotool$
```

*Then* you can checkout a commit:

```
~/xdotool$ git checkout edbbb7a
Note: checking out 'edbbb7a'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
...

HEAD is now at edbbb7a... Add --repeat and --repeat-delay to allow repetition of a 
key sequence with an optional delay in between each full sequence.
```

BTW, if you need to return from detached HEAD, the command is `git checkout master`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i followed what you sayd but dont i need to merge it into the program? becouse i still get an error when i try to run xdotool

Comment: Per the [instructions](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/126#issuecomment-240618974), once you `git checkout edbbb7a`, you need to `make install`.

Comment: i did that and these error showed up:  'make: cc: Command not found', 'Makefile:121: recipe for target 'xdo.o' failed' and 'make: *** [xdo.o] Error 127'

Comment: @RapidGainz You need to install a c compiler like `gcc`.

Comment: did that and still gives these errors:  'Makefile:121: recipe for target 'xdo.o' failed' and 'make: *** [xdo.o] Error 1' and 'xdo.c:24:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory #include <X11/Xlib.h>'

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out to a git tag or branch if the version you want is tagged.

OR

Try checking out with only a part of the commit, so in your case:

```
git checkout edbbb7a8
```

Also recheck if this commit really exists

Comment: this is the link of the commit https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/commit/edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8 so it does exist, and what do you mean by git tag or branch? also i follow this post https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/126#issuecomment-240618974

Comment: so what I said doesn't work ?